# Error occur in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

This app is getting data directly from API. When it goes to run such type of error occurs. Basically I think the error occurs in the getItemCount() method but i'm not be able to resolve the problem. I've attached the error file and the whole code.I shall be thankful if you can resolve the error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                at
>   com.techbrightsoft.database.MyRecyler.getItemCount(MyRecyler.java:36)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3603)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3103)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
>                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
>                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

```
  public class MyRecyler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyler.MyHolder> {
  private Context context;
   private ArrayList<String> names;

    public MyRecyler(Context context, ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.names, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(this.names.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return names.size();
    }

    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<String> authors_names ;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // Downloading Data From Internet
        DownloadingData downloadingData = new DownloadingData();
        downloadingData.execute("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=a301a9e90c774b4ebf7eb21000cdbdef");


        // RecyclerView Set
        MyRecyler recyler = new MyRecyler(MainActivity.this,authors_names);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyler.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you initialising `authors_names`, your arraylist has no data i think

Comment: I initialize  authors_names in main activity as arraylist

Comment: yes you have declared it, but where are you passing data to the arraylist

Comment: The array list you are passing to your recycler is null

Comment: I am passing data from DownloadData class

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            String names = object.getString("articles");
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(names);

            for (int i=0 ; i<array.length() ; i++){
                JSONObject list_of_names = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String l = list_of_names.getString("author");
                MainActivity.authors_names.add(l);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}}}

Comment: That or the content in it is null...

Comment: when you first attach adapter, array is still `null` because result is not yet ready and that cause exception. See my reply.

Comment: Set the RecyclerView in a callback function. The API call might not be done in time.

Comment: @SmartProgrammer add your json response, you may not be parsing it properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code does not properly initialize `authors_names`. If I have guess your code logic correctly, you want to fill `authors_names` with result from `downloadingData`. Generally, passing that list to your adapter is a bad practice.

My suggestion is initializing `names` with an empty list and define a `addAll()` method for updating its content. A simple and unoptimized implementation will be like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

public void addAll(ArrayList<String> items) {
    names.clear();
    names.addAll(items);
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

And you need to add items with `addAll()` method from main code when `downloadingData` finished its job(normally through an callback).